# Sublime Text 3 redefine keybindings for Jump Back/Forward

Tags: sublimetext3

<strike>In Sublime Text 3 the default keybindings for Jump Back/Forward are `"alt+minus" / "alt+shift+minus"` correspondingly. Trying to redefine it to some other hotkey (like`"alt+left" / "alt+right"`) didn't work for me.
I was trying the solution described in [Sublime Navigation History](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Navigation%20History) plugin:</strike>

> **ST3**
>
> This plugin is no longer needed for ST3, as of build 3019 Navigation History has been natively added via the new Jump Back and
>   Jump Forward commands. They are called "jump_back" and "jump_forward"
>   and you can add them to your key bindings (Preferences -> Key Bindings
>   - User) with the following snippet:
>
> { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+left"], "command": "jump_back" },   { "keys":
>   ["ctrl+alt+right"], "command": "jump_forward" }

I have tried various keybinding combinations, but none of them seem to trigger jump back/forward commands. And I couldn't find the default keybindings for jump back/forward commands in the default preferences file.

What am I missing?

P.S.: Sublime Text Version 3.1.1, Build 3176; OS Win7x64

Sorry, my mistake. Haven't noticed a **typo** in command name. Case closed.

Answer (score 1):

First here is the default binding for jump_back and jump_forward :

```
`{ "keys": ["alt+keypad_minus"], "command": "jump_back" },
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+keypad_minus"], "command": "jump_forward" },
{ "keys": ["alt+-"], "command": "jump_back" },
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+-"], "command": "jump_forward" },`
```

Then to set your own binding properties you should modify the right panel (empty by default) with your binding like this :
    
    `[
        {"keys": ["alt+left"], "command":"jump_back"},
        {"keys": ["alt+right"], "command":"jump_forward"}
    ]`